# Magento admin - Two Ajax calls are going while changing country on place Order form

Tags: magento

A bug in magento core it seems but when i reported to magento support they have tried and said that they are not able to reproduce. Even i have attached the screen cast. Please check and put your comments so we can get this fixed. Atlease magento support will accept that there is issue.

**Steps to Reproduce.**

- Magento Admin --> Sales --> Order --> Create New Order --> Create New Customer or Select Customer --> Change Country
- Before doing this please Enable fire bug console to see the xmlHttpRequest is going twice.

Comment: there's only 1 request going in 1.7.. What Magento version you're using? may be you have custom module or functionality for this cause.

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh .... We are using 1.12 EE . But i am pretty sure that this is exists in the core. I've tried in blank magento version too.